# Dev-Cpp: Error message when compiling „mingw32-make.exe: *** [Test6_main.o] Error -1073741502”

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, dev-c++

I installed Dev-Cpp 5.11 with TDM-GCC 4.9.2 on my Windows 7 PC. Everything worked perfectly. My PC has been upgraded to Windows 10. Since then I keep getting an error message while compiling: A window with the title „g++.exe – Anwendungsfehler“ and the error message „Die Anwendung konnte nicht korrekt gestartet werden (0xc0000142). Klicken Sie auf "OK", um die Anwendung zu schließen“ opens.

The following is in the compile log of Dev-Cpp:

```
    Compiling project changes...
--------
- Project Filename: C:\Ziegler\BS\Test6\Test6.dev
- Compiler Name: TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release

Building makefile...
--------
- Filename: C:\Ziegler\BS\Test6\Makefile.win

Processing makefile...
--------
- Makefile Processor: C:\DevCpp\MinGW64\bin\mingw32-make.exe
- Command: mingw32-make.exe -f "C:\Ziegler\BS\Test6\Makefile.win" all

g++.exe -c Test6_main.cpp -o Test6_main.o -I"C:/DevCpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/DevCpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/DevCpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/DevCpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++" 

C:\Ziegler\BS\Test6\Makefile.win:28: recipe for target 'Test6_main.o' failed

mingw32-make.exe: *** [Test6_main.o] Error -1073741502


Compilation results...
--------
- Errors: 0
- Warnings: 0
- Compilation Time: 3,78s
```

If I execute the following commands in the console (cmd), the .cpp is compiled and linked and the Test6.exe is then in the project folder:

```
g++.exe -c Test6_main.cpp -o Test6_main.o -I"C:/DevCpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/DevCpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/DevCpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/DevCpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++"

g++.exe Test6_main.o -o Test6.exe -L"C:/DevCpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/DevCpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Dev-C++?

Comment: Yes, several times. DevCpp runs perfectly on my private PC (also Windows 10). I only have the error on my PC from work.

Comment: @ziggo Could you translate the error messages. I don't trust google translate.

Comment: I'll try: A window with the title „g++.exe – Application error“ and the error message „The application could not be started correctly (0xc0000142). Click "OK" to close the application“ opens. I hope it helps!

Comment: Are you sure the g++.exe is the same used from console and Dev-Cpp? Thinking perhaps a cygwin install or similar is interfering somehow

Comment: How can I find out which "g++.exe" is used by the console? I have three compilers on my PC. Windows search found the following directories with "g++.exe": "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr32\avr32-gnu-toolchain\avr32\bin", "C:\WinAVR-20100110\avr\bin", "C:\WinAVR-20100110\avr32\bin", "C:\Users\michael.ziegler\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps" and "C:\DevCpp\MinGW64\bin".